# Transfer files form Windows Qt application to Linux and execute it

Tags: c++, qt

**Background of project** -> I have to upgrade the Linux embedded system remotely. This requires to transfer the tar ball file from Windows Qt application to Linux box connected via Ethernet cable. The Linux box has fixed IP address.

**What I have done so far** -> Being complete novice in Qt, I have created a dialog box to browse the file and check tar ball file.

**Issues** -> Now I want that when I click another button, say *Upgrade*, it should transfer the files from Windows to Linux box (that has fixed IP address) and execute the bash script which has code how to upgrade different files.

May you guys please throw some light how would I send files from Windows to Linux box. I have looked at FTP client of Qt and I guess it downloads the file instead of transferring it.

Thanks and regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) My batch script say upgrade.bat accepts 2 parameters  like ip address , upgrade tar ball
then using putty.exe it transfers the file to linux machine connected via ethernet cable.
 example in bat script

> pscp -pw "blabla" "%TARGET_UPDATE_FILE%"
>   user@"%TARGET_IP%":"%BASE_DIR%"/

where  target_update_file = tar ball file  accept from Qt and  target ip = ip address received as parameter to bat file from qt .

Now on qt , in upgrade button code

```
void Qt_test::ReadOut()     
{       
     QProcess *processInfo = dynamic_cast< QProcess* >( sender() );

   if( processInfo )
     {
       ui->upgrade_info->append( processInfo->readAllStandardOutput() );
     }        
 }    

void Qt_test::ReadError()
{
     QProcess *processInfo = dynamic_cast< QProcess* >( sender() );

    if( processInfo )
   {
       ui->upgrade_info->append( processInfo->readAllStandardError() );
   }
 }

void Qt_test::on_file_browse_clicked()
{
     ui->selected_file->setText( QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( this, tr( "Open File" ),
                                                        "/home",
                                                        tr( "Upgrade file ( *.tar.gz )"     ) ) );
 }

void  Qt_test::on_file_upgrade_clicked()
 {
        QFileInfo upgradeFileInfo( ui->selected_file->text() );
        if( !upgradeFileInfo.exists() )
       {
             QMessageBox::information( this, tr( "Information" ),
                             tr( "Unable to find file for upgrading!" ) );
            return;
       }     

    QString batchPath= QDir::currentPath() + "\\testUpgrade.bat" ;
    QFileInfo batchFile( batchPath ) ;
    if( !batchFile.exists() )
    {
             QMessageBox::information( this, tr( "Information" ),
                             tr("Failed to find the upgrade batch file....... ") ) ;
         return;
     }

    //Check if cmd.exe is present in Clients system and is located at correct path
       QFileInfo cmdFile( "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");
     if( !cmdFile.exists() )
      {
           QMessageBox::information( this, tr( "Information" ),
                             tr("Failed to find the cmd.exe ... Check cmd.exe is   installed and is in  C:\\Windows\\system32\\ !") ) ;
          return;
      }

     QFileInfo puttyFile( "C:\\Windows\\system32\\putty.exe");
     if( !puttyFile.exists() )
     {
           QMessageBox::information( this, tr( "Information" ),
                              tr("Failed to find the putty.exe ... Check putty.exe(ideally version 0.62.0.0) is installed and is in  C:\\Windows\\system32\\ !") ) ;
          return;
     }

      QFileInfo plinkFile( "C:\\Windows\\system32\\plink.exe");
     if( !plinkFile.exists() )
     {
          QMessageBox::information( this, tr( "Information" ),
                              tr("Failed to find the plink.exe ... Check plink.exe(ideally version 0.62.0.0) is installed and is in  C:\\Windows\\system32\\ !") ) ;
          return;
     }

    QString upgradeFile =   upgradeFileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
   QString ipAddress   =   ui->selected_ip->text();
    qDebug() << " checksum valu is " <<checkSum.count() ;
    QStringList arguments ;

    arguments << " /c" << batchFile.absoluteFilePath()<< upgradeFile << ipAddress ;
   // copying update
   QProcess *processUpgrade = new QProcess( this );
   if( processUpgrade )
    {   std::cout <<" starting to upgrade " << std::endl ;

       processUpgrade->setEnvironment( QProcess::systemEnvironment() )  ;
       processUpgrade->setProcessChannelMode( QProcess::MergedChannels ) ;

        processUpgrade->start( cmdFile.absoluteFilePath(), arguments ) ;
        processUpgrade->waitForStarted() ;
        connect( processUpgrade, SIGNAL( readyReadStandardOutput() ), this, SLOT( ReadOut() ) ) ;
          connect( processUpgrade, SIGNAL( readyReadStandardError()  ), this, SLOT( ReadErr() ) ) ;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Both QFtp and QNetworkAccessManager classes can upload files to FTP server. QNetworkAccessManager class would be even better for your job than QFtp. However, it would require a certain setup on your linux box. 
You can also transfer the file using TCP Socket connection (see classes [QTcpServer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html) and [QTcpSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpsocket.html)), this also requires additional application running on linux. So if you want to automate the process I guess you could write either one Qt application that uploads the file on FTP server running on your linux box, or create two simple applications that would work as a client and server.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. While I was googling , I found QProcess and I thought if I use something like ` QProcess *process;      process->start( "scp -pw rootpsswd c:\tmp\foo.tar.gz root@10.10.10.10:/home/guest/");`  and then execute another command which will call bash script inside linux box to untar the file and do required things.  Do you think this approach is good?

Comment: @samantha This code would simply start `scp` (secure copy), which is part of the SSH suite of many Linux distributions. If you only want to transfer files from Windows to Linux, why not use a normal (S)FTP client? Do you *need* to write your own client here?

Comment: @ Gnosophilon , Thanks for replying. Well , The linux box already has ftp client. The Qt apps on windows is just a small app which browse file and trhough pushbutton should upgrade file on linux machine/box. With Upgrade I mean it should transfer the tarball into linux machine and run bashscript which will untar file , check check sum etc etc

Comment: @samantha For this scenario to work, you require *shell access* on the Linux machine. Why not use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to transfer the file and [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty) to access the Linux machine via SSH and untar it?

Comment: @ Gnosophilon ,  yeah now I am executing a batch sript which will copy teh files remotely and do teh require job .  Thanks everyone for teh advice

Comment: @samantha Could you describe your approach and add an answer to this post? This would be helpeful other people stumbling upon this question.

Comment: @Gnososphilon..... Selfish on my part that i forget to write my method here... I will post my solution tomorrow... thanks for reminding me